# My Monero have never arrived from Kraken to my Monero GUI wallet. Please help!

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

this is my first time sending XMR and I am kind of nervous. I recently sent 7.78443 xmr from Kraken to my wallet (Monero GUI) I had downloaded less than a week ago from the official monero site. I read some answers here on reddit and stackoverflow but call me dumb, I didn't find any solution to my problem. Back to my issue, I have not received it and it has had over 50 confirmations on the transaction. The balance still shows 0. I followed a help thread to get me to this site: https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html and my results are:

This address owns output 0 with pubkey: fa252df8966e077f5ee22fd2c66dcbd1ee2b8a9681161c3e86270c0176cf630d for amount: 7.78443

This address doesn't own output 1 with pubkey: a4185caa8abcc1c8d70960ace24ff92e3517503cce7851337adaabc3fddaef18 for amount: Confidential

Total received: 7.78443

Also, I followed the advice from dEBRUYNE and I checked also the xmrchain.net resutlted to the following:

Outputs (2)

output public key   amount  output match?

00: fa252df8966e077f5ee22fd2c66dcbd1ee2b8a9681161c3e86270c0176cf630d    7.784430000000  true

01: a4185caa8abcc1c8d70960ace24ff92e3517503cce7851337adaabc3fddaef18    ?   false

My GUI wallet is fully synced. I cannot seem to find my daemon address though( dEBRUYNE says it 's under the debug info and it  should state localhost (or 127.0.0.1) with port 18081).I see nothing of this kind. It says:

GUI version: v0.12.0.0

Embedded Monero version: v0.12.0.0

Wallet creation height: 0 (click to change)
--blank block to fill in a number--

Wallet log path: --I will not share this one ok?--

Wallet name: --not sharing this one, only if needed--

Daemon log path: --also not sharing this--

I am curious about the wallet creation height that is 0, . Do you think that plays a role in my problem?

Both heights in show status are identical.

What can I do? Can someone help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Adding this ^ such that we can mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

No need guys to answer. After an hour I wrote my question, my problem was resolved . I followed the instructions of the member dEBRUYNE and restarted twice the GUI, first without stopping the deamon and the second time with stopping deamon. I do not know if that was the solution but thank God, my XMR are showing now in my Moner wallet GUI. Yeah!